# Como obtener un objeto con Jira rest Api

Tags: api, rest, jira

estoy iniciando con esto de la rest api de jira y estoy algo confundido sobre como obtener un objeto según los parámetros indicados y según el usuario que tenga asignado este objeto

he intentado lo siguiente

http://trtstjirfe1:8080/rest/ insight/1.0/iql/objects?includeAttributes=true&iql=Component_Type=KEYBOARD and Brand = MICROSOFT and Model = "Natural Ergonomic" and inboundReferences(Usr_Code = 40000162)&includeAttributesDeep=2

segun tengo entendio el inboundReferences(iql) debería buscar en las referencias entrantes y filtrar los que cumplan con la consulta iql, pero al parecer lo estoy usando mal ya que me salta este error

IQL "Tipo_Componente=TECLADO and Marca = MICROSOFT and Modelo = "Natural Ergonomic" and inboundReferences(Codigo_usr = 40000162)" has invalid syntax at position 101 with error message "mismatched input '(' expecting {OPERATOR, REFERENCE_OPERATOR, IS_OPERATOR, ' '}"

podrían guiarme en como podría obtener este objeto
[image: Objeto que deseo obtener según los atributos marcados]

[image: Usuario que tiene asignado es objeto a obtener]

Me estoy guiando en la siguiente documentación
https://docs.atlassian.com/assets/REST/9.1.16/#iql-findObjects

De antemano muchas gracias por su ayuda.